# java android RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT returns -2

Tags: java, android

I want to display a value from height relativeLayouts. A relativelayouts heigh is  `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT` but I set this in code (no in xml). How I can display a value (int or long ) ?

```
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                Log.e("sdasdas", "dsfdsfdsfsdf");
                downX = event.getX();
                downY = event.getY();
                return true;
            }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {

                upX = event.getX();
                upY = event.getY();

                float deltaX = downX - upX;
                float deltaY = downY - upY;
                final ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = MainActivity.relativeLayout1.getLayoutParams();
                if (deltaY < 0) {
                    if (relativeLayout1.getHeight() > (int) activity.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.dimen_entry_in_dp2) + 1)
                        params.height = (int) activity.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.dimen_entry_in_dp2);
                    else {
                        params.height = (int) activity.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.dimen_entry_in_dp);
                        MainActivity.listView1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
//                    relativeLayout1.setLayoutParams(params);
                    view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    collapse(relativeLayout1, 400, params.height);
//                    MainActivity.listView1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } else {
//                    params.height = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
                    if (relativeLayout1.getHeight() < (int) activity.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.dimen_entry_in_dp2)) {
                        Log.e("size " , (int) activity.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.dimen_entry_in_dp2) + " size 2 : " + RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                        if ((int) activity.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.dimen_entry_in_dp2)> RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT) {
                            params.height = (int) activity.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.dimen_entry_in_dp2);
                        } else {
                            params.height = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
                        }
                    } else {
                        params.height = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
                        Log.e("size " , (int) activity.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.dimen_entry_in_dp2) + " size 2 : " + ((int) RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT) + " sieze 3 : " + params.height) ;
                    }
//                    MainActivity.relativeLayout1.setLayoutParams(params);
                    expand(relativeLayout1, 400, params.height);
                    view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    MainActivity.listView1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

                return false; // no swipe horizontally and no swipe vertically
            }
            // case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Can you please add some more code?

Comment: @MayurRaval I edit my post

Comment: This is because 

`@Deprecated
        public static final int FILL_PARENT = -1;
        public static final int MATCH_PARENT = -1;
        public static final int WRAP_CONTENT = -2;` in android sdk

Comment: You can not do ` params.height = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;` as `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT` will not return height

Comment: @MayurRaval so can I check a height of value from wrap_content ?

Comment: You can get height from `view.getHeight()`